# Usar as rotas do Angular direto do arquivo HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Preciso desenvolver uma app offline onde ele será acessado direto do arquivo HTML, até onde sei o Angular precisa do protocolo HTTP para realizar as rotas ainda.

Ex.: Na URL ficara assim `file://angular-project/index.html/#/lista` ao invés de `http://localhost/angular-project/#/lista`

Preciso que funcione com o  `file://`

Answer (score 2):

Sua aplicação offline pode fazer uso de Application Cache.

Basicamente, você precisará criar um arquivo `manifest` contendo uma menção a todos os arquivos que você deseja oferecer em modo offline.

Quando solicitado, o browser tentará carregar primeiramente os arquivos do *Application cache*, para só então tentar estabelecer uma conexão HTTP com o servidor.

(Caso novas versões de ao menos um dos arquivos esteja disponível, você pode então tentar recarregar a aplicação.)

Este mecanismo é compatível com `Routes` e `States` do AngularJS.

Referências para consulta:

http://www.w3c.br/cursos/html5/conteudo/capitulo22.html
http://diveintohtml5.com.br/offline.html

Comment: Sim com o Application Cache funciona, mas o problema é que o usuário não vai acessar a aplicação pela internet ela ira ser distribuída a partir do pendrive, sendo assim não terá conexão HTTP, será acessado direto do arquivo HTML

Comment: Eu não recomendaria este modelo por dois motivos: Em várias circunstâncias browsers consideram conteúdo local como 'inseguro', forçando você a baixar os requisitos de segurança para seu código rodar. Segundo, a resolução de permissões e nomes parciais ocorre de maneira diferente em diferentes browsers. Sugestão: Faça sua distribuição com um serviço web portátil como o Z-WAMP (http://zwamp.sourceforge.net/).